# MEF - List of DLLs to load

Tags: mef

We have many products that will share common DLLs.  For a product, I would like to indicate a specific list of DLLs to include in the catalog.  I know I can do this:

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MainWindow).Assembly));

string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\Folder\With\Plugins", "SomePlugin.dll");
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(fullPath);
ComposablePartCatalog assemblyCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(dll);
catalog.Catalogs.Add(assemblyCatalog);

_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Would looping in the middle part for each specific file be the best method?

Answer (score 0):

MEF provides a **DirectoryCatalog**. All you have to do is point the directory that contains the plugins and it will handle the rest, no loop necessary. Something like this:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\Folder\With\Plugins");    
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(fullPath);
_container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
_container.ComposeParts(this);
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but it doesn't mean that every DLL located in that directory has to be loaded for that particular product.  That's why I would need some kind of list for **specific** DLLs to say "This product uses DLLs A, B and C while this other product uses DLLs B, C, D, E and F".

Comment: Are "products" different applications? Then maybe they can read the folder path from config and load whatever DLL is in that folder by using the DirectoryCatalog.